# How to change the code as more Scala-like one regarding in the point of resource close?

Tags: scala, amazon-s3

Below is the scala code that use `s3 client` and open the `s3 bucket` and read the object.

```
  def readS3(
                            region: String,
                            bucket: String,
                            key: String,
                            fromLine: Int,
                            toLine: Int,
                            lineSeparator: String,
                          ): String = {
    val client = S3Client.builder()
      .region(Region.of(region))
      .build()
    val objectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
      .key(key)
      .bucket(bucket)
      .build()
    val objectBytes = client.getObjectAsBytes(objectRequest)
    val in = objectBytes.asInputStream()
    val bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))
    try {
      val sb = readLine(fromLine, toLine, 1, lineSeparator, bufferedReader, new mutable.StringBuilder)
      sb.toString
    } finally {
      in.close()
      bufferedReader.close()
      client.close()
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I tried to close all the resource-related objects in the `finally` clause.
However, I think that I can change the code as more Scala-like version
because it seems to be Java-like as I think.
I think that in the code above instead of creating `s3 client` object every time, I am able to use `lazy` keyword to prevent creating every `s3 client` object.
And also, I didn't like the way that I use the close in the `finally` clause.
Instead of closing the resourcing in the `finally`, is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Note that I am using the Scala version `2.12`, so I cannot `use` command for resource management.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks fine. Excepted maybe if the close can themselves throw exceptions.

Comment: You can backport `Using` of Scala 2.13 by using https://github.com/scala/scala-collection-compat if you prefer though.

Comment: If you are using plain **Scala** this is fine, if you can add `Using` then better. - Another option would be to use an effect system like **cats-effect** and use `Resource` for this... but that is probably way too much for a simple method.

Comment: Your code looks fine. I am pretty sure, you don't need `in.close()` (closing the reader will take care of it). Suspect that `bufferedReader.close()` is also redundant, 
because `client.close()` will close underlying connections anyhow.